Why is the ordinal logit also called POLR?
The ordinal logit is often referred to as proportional odds logistic regression (POLR, e.g. in R). I am wondering where the term proportional is coming from?
It is clear to me that the logit model is using log odds and that the logistic function is just another way of expressing / rearranging the link function in GLMs. If e.g. $G$ is the link function logit would denote $G^{-1}$ while logistic function would denote $G$.
I know that we can introduce the ordinal logit by a latent variable $y_i*$:
\begin{equation*}
    y_i^* = x_i^T \beta + \epsilon_i
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    y_i = j \quad \text{if} \quad \alpha_{j-1} < y_i^* \leq \alpha_j
\end{equation*}
Looking at the thresholds and combining it with the fact that the $\beta$'s are constant over all categories, I can imagine some sort of proportionality could be built in. But I guess that does not yet sufficiently explain what is meant by proportional odds.

Suppose you have three ordered categories $1,2,3$ and you are looking for modelled probability functions $p_1(\mathbf x),p_2(\mathbf x),p_3(\mathbf x)$ summing to $1$.  Then the proportionate odds assumption seems to be that $\dfrac{p_1(\mathbf x)}{p_2(\mathbf x)+p_3(\mathbf x)}\Big{/}{\dfrac{p_1(\mathbf x)+p_2(\mathbf x)}{p_3(\mathbf x)}}$  is constant as $\mathbf x$ varies, and similarly for more ordered categories.
